# Can we alter pandas cross tabulation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded raw_data from MySQL using sqlalchemy and pymysql

`engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://[user]:[passwd]@[host]:[port]/[database]')`

`df = pd.read_sql_table('data', engine)`

df is something like this

```
| Age Category | Category       |
|--------------|----------------|
| 31-26        | Engaged        |
| 26-31        | Engaged        |
| 31-36        | Not Engaged    |
| Above 51     | Engaged        |
| 41-46        | Disengaged     |
| 46-51        | Nearly Engaged |
| 26-31        | Disengaged     |
```

Then i had performed analysis as follow

`age = pd.crosstab(df['Age Category'], df['Category'])`

```
| Category     | A | B  | C  | D |
|--------------|---|----|----|---|
| Age Category |   |    |    |   |
| 21-26        | 2 | 2  | 4  | 1 |
| 26-31        | 7 | 11 | 12 | 5 |
| 31-36        | 3 | 5  | 5  | 2 |
| 36-41        | 2 | 4  | 1  | 7 |
| 41-46        | 0 | 1  | 3  | 2 |
| 46-51        | 0 | 0  | 2  | 3 |
| Above 51     | 0 | 3  | 0  | 6 |
```

I want to change it to
Pandas DataFrame something like this.

```
| Age Category | A | B  | C  | D |
|--------------|---|----|----|---|
| 21-26        | 2 | 2  | 4  | 1 |
| 26-31        | 7 | 11 | 12 | 5 |
| 31-36        | 3 | 5  | 5  | 2 |
| 36-41        | 2 | 4  | 1  | 7 |
| 41-46        | 0 | 1  | 3  | 2 |
| 46-51        | 0 | 0  | 2  | 3 |
| Above 51     | 0 | 3  | 0  | 6 |
```

Thank you for your time and consideration

Comment: Is the change purely visual? Can you share some information on the DataFrame, not just a prettified output?

Comment: Yes, a df.to_dict() would be great to have

Comment: just drop the first row

Comment: @AlexanderCécile by category.dtypes I am getting `Engagement Category
Disengaged            int64
Not Engaged           int64
Nearly Engaged        int64
Engaged               int64
Total                 int64
% Disengaged        float64
% Not Engaged       float64
% Nearly Engaged    float64
% Engaged           float64
dtype: object`

Comment: Please just share all relevant code and data. It’s better than having to extract information piece by piece. See: [mcve].

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Please check the question now

Comment: @luigigi dropping the first row giving me `KeyError: 'Category'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both texts are called columns and index names, solution for change them is use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
age = age.rename_axis(index=None, columns='Age Category')
```

Or set columns names by index names, and then set index names to default - `None`:

```
age.columns.name = age.index.name
age.index.name = None
```

---

```
print (age)
Age Category  Disengaged  Engaged  Nearly Engaged  Not Engaged
26-31                  1        1               0            0
31-26                  0        1               0            0
31-36                  0        0               0            1
41-46                  1        0               0            0
46-51                  0        0               1            0
Above 51               0        1               0            0
```

But this texts are something like metadata, so some functions should remove them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @jezrael. You are genius.